# Server-side video conversion and compression

Tags: php, compression, video-conversion

I want to provide an automatic video-converter for my CMS-customers. They should be able to upload their "untouched" video-files (MP4, VMV, AVI, ...) and my server compresses and converts it to a Web-friendly MP4-file (exactly like YouTube makes it).

The result is clear:

- Web-friendly MP4-format
- Compressed to tolerable file size

So I'm looking for a PHP-API or Linux-shell-script to realise this.

Is there a easy way to handle this?

---

**Edit**: YouTube-embedded videos are not a solution for me.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at http://www.ffmpeg.org/ it's pretty much the go-to library for this sort of thing.

I found a PHP driver for it [here](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) that looks interesting but I've not tried it. Still, it's easy enough to run the shell commands directly from PHP if needed.

Comment: Yes, I will run it directly from PHP via exec(); I look how it works now. Thanks.

Comment: @Luca Nate Mahler, did you ever get this working as you described? I am looking into a similar set up.

Comment: @DavidMcCarran Not really :/