# How can I compress an uploaded video on my server?

Tags: javascript, php, html, video-compression

I have to make a simple web page on which user can upload a video (max 10 MB) and the page will compress it (to 5 MB or less) and save it to the server.

I have done the front-end part of the webpage using HTML CSS and javascript.

The user should be able to add a video file and my site should compress it on the server side.

So, How can I compress the uploaded video on my server?

[image: screenshot of my page]

Comment: The compression is supposed to be done using server side languages but not frontend i.e JavaScript.

Comment: I think it can become a security issue to compress it client-side. By the way you have not precised what is used front-end (probably javascript?). Client could alter the code as to modify format checks and such. Video should be checked and compressed server-side

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26591690/server-side-video-conversion-and-compression/26591914#26591914

Comment: yes server-side compression @Mr_Green

Comment: i've update the question ... i'm looking for server side code to compress the videos uplodad on my site. @Kaddath

Comment: Are you sure the code answered in that question works ? @HyyanAboFakher

Comment: nothing soo far :( but i'm considering to use FFmpeg on my server @AniketSahrawat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wants to reduce video size without loosing much quality, then you can install and use one of the following programs:

```
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
ffmpeg -i videoS1.mp4 -r 30 -s 960x540 output-compress.mp4
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install mencoder
mencoder input.mp4 -vf scale=720:480 -ovc lavc -o output-compress.mp4
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get install libav-tools 
avconv -i input.mp4 -s 640x480 output-compress.mp4
```

Above all commands/programs can be executed using Server side programming language as  it's Linux utilities. You may get libraries for various codec support.

Comment: *do note*: This would require full access to the server or a hosting company that is willing to install these tools

Comment: So if i want to add ffmpeg ... i have to install the program on my server ? @DarkBee

Comment: Yes, use one of above mentioned library in your server. that will install that program, and you can use

Comment: For windows you can download ffmpeg library.